# Modifying "On Marriage" in "The Prophet"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to modify the poem "On Marriage" (written by Khalil Gibran) for use in a wedding invitation card. Specifically, I want to change all the second-person pronouns to first-person pronouns. For example: you->we, your->our, etc.

However, I got confused about how to modify "Give one another of your bread but eat not from the same loaf."

Can I say "Give one another of one’s bread but eat not from the same loaf"? Does this look strange?

Below are the original poem and the modified poem. Any suggestions are welcome.

The complete original poem is:

> You were born together, and together you shall be for evermore. 
>   You shall be together when the white wings of death scatter your days.
>   Aye, you shall be together even in the silent memory of God. But let
>   there be spaces in your togetherness. And let the winds of the heavens
>   dance between you.
>
> Love one another, but make not a bond of love; Let it rather be a
>   moving sea between the shores of your souls. Fill each other’s cup but
>   drink not from one cup. Give one another of your bread but eat not
>   from the same loaf. Sing and dance together and be joyous, but let
>   each one of you be alone, Even as the strings of a lute are alone
>   though they quiver with the same music.
>
> Give your hearts, but not into each other’s keeping. For only the hand
>   of Life can contain your hearts. And stand together yet not too near
>   together, For the pillars of the temple stand apart, And the oak tree
>   and the cypress grow not in each other’s shadow.

The complete modified poem is:

> We were born together, and together we shall be for evermore. We shall
>   be together when the white wings of death scatter our days. Aye, we
>   shall be together even in the silent memory of God. But let there be
>   spaces in our togetherness. And let the winds of the heavens dance
>   between us.
>
> Love one another, but make not a bond of love; Let it rather be a
>   moving sea between the shores of our souls. Fill each other’s cup but
>   drink not from one cup. Give one another of one’s bread but eat not
>   from the same loaf. Sing and dance together and be joyous, but let
>   each one of us be alone, Even as the strings of a lute are alone
>   though they quiver with the same music.
>
> Give our hearts, but not into each other’s keeping. For only the hand
>   of Life can contain our hearts. And stand together yet not too near
>   together, For the pillars of the temple stand apart, And the oak tree
>   and the cypress grow not in each other’s shadow.

Comment: “Give one another of one’s bread but eat not from the same loaf” looks strange to me; but I find the original strange also, and somewhat specious. Why not talk to whoever chose that poem and get them to choose something else?

Comment: Just thought the following article interesting and the journalist's words worth bearing in mind http://www.ncregister.com/blog/jennifer-fulwiler/please-dont-read-this-poem-at-your-wedding

Comment: I'd suggest using a different imperative : "Let's give each other of our bread" ... perhaps

Answer (score 1):

*Give one another of one’s bread but eat not from the same loaf* does sound a bit odd.  But the problem is not the pronoun, it's the point of view.  In the original, the speaker is talking to a group of people, sometimes speaking in the imperative.

In the new version, it is unclear.  Sometimes, the two people are talking to each other, saying the same thing, as in agreement.  In the imperative sentences, they are each giving the same command to each.  The transformation still works here.

However, in the phrase "love one another", this breaks down.  "One another" implies that the person speaking is giving the command to at least two people, for a total of three.  However, the "we" is only two people.  This implies that the point of view has shifted from
the two people talking to each other to a third person talking to them.  The sentence you mentioned has the same problem.

I suggest using changing from imperative to declarative and use *each other* instead of *one another*.  Then the sentence becomes *We shall give each other of our bread...*  I think this transformation would improve all the imperative sentences.  In a similar way, the sentences with "let there be" could be changed to "there shall be", but I think they would be fine either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely determined to use this poem as your starting point, I'd suggest that you replace the second-person-plural imperatives ("Love one another", "Fill each other's cup", etc.) with first-person-plural declarative statements ("We must love one another", "We must fill each other's cup").

Also, you'll have to reverse the word order of some of those archaic formulations. For instance,

> “Give one another of one’s bread but **eat not** from the same loaf”

would become

> “**We must give** one another of **our** [own] bread but **not eat** from the same loaf”.

Finally, I'd strongly recommend that you run the revised text past at least two native speakers of English whose linguistic sensitivity you trust before you reproduce it in your invitation card. (That sappy poem is going to need all the help it can get.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are not changing just the nouns from second person to third person, but also the verbs. It may not seem like it, because the form is the same in English for all persons and number except third person singular (he help**s**). So if you want to be consistent, just keep changing from second person plural to first person plural.

This applies to the imperatives too, where the form changes from:

*Give one another of your bread but eat not from the same loaf.*

to

*Let us give each other of our bread but not eat from the same loaf.*

By the way, *Love one another, but make not a bond of love*

would become

*Let us love each other, but not make a bond of love.*

Note the replacement of *one another* with *each other.* That sounds more natural to me.

And so forth. I'm just telling you what the forms would be, because answering the question *what you should do* is to express an opinion and be off-topic.